Ho fix the error: remote calls to the SAM database have been denied in the past 900 seconds throttling window
What I am doing is running a PowerShell script that goes to Azure to obtain information about the shared mailboxes, this from an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API. After some policies were applied to the server, this process stopped working.
In Windows Server event viewer, I find this error:

Remote calls to the SAM database have been denied in the past 900 seconds throttling window. For more information please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=787651. An ice day to play Bear with us as we head north for International Po
[09:23] xxxxxxx + System           -  Provider            [ Name] Microsoft-Windows-Directory-Services-SAM            [ Guid] {0d4fdc09-8c27-494a-bda0-505e4fd8adae}              EventID 16969           Version 0           Level   3           Task    0           Opcode  0           Keywords    0x8000000000000000           -  TimeCreated             [ SystemTime]   2024-02-26T22:33:56.131767200Z              EventRecordID   136791           -  Correlation             [ ActivityID]   {4fc83eb7-6715-0003-ef3e-c84f1567da01}           -  Execution           [ ProcessID]    776             [ ThreadID] 3468            Channel System              Computer    SACCP122P.grupoins.local         -  Security            [ UserID]   S-1-5-18 -  EventData       Throttle window:    900         Suppressed Message Count:   1

The API has worked before applying the policy, so I need to provide some kind of exception to the policy to remove this specifically from the Windows server.
